# Retrieve a HTML elements id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to obtain the id of an element (div, input etc) using jQuery and how?

Comment: Incredibly simple jquery questions: the ultimate rep jackpot!

Comment: No need to use jQuery. `element.id` is all you need (as long as it is **one element** of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Attributes/attr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr)

Simple example:

```
alert($('div.someclass').attr('id'));
```

If there is more than one div with the class `someclass` (that is to say, the selector returns more than one element), you can get them all by looping through the elements using [each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each), and pushing the ids into an array for example:

```
var ids = [];
$('div.someclass').each(function() {
     ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Just to go a little further, you can use [attribute filters](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) (in this case [`attributeHas`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeHas#attribute)) to pick out only those elements that have ids, e.g.:

```
var ids = [];
$('div[id]').each(function() {
     ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

and finally, instead of using each, you can use [`map( callback )`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/map) which provides a neater way of doing the above:

```
var ids = $('div[id]').map(function(index, domElement) {
    return $(domElement).attr('id');
}).get();
alert(ids.join(","));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('elementselector').attr('id');
```

You would need to pick a proper selector to make sure you select the element of interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).attr('id')
```

Comment: If you already have the element, as in your example, it'd be clearer and faster to just do element.id